# What is Alef Hamza?

Tags: search, criteria, arabic, documentviewer

I found this one, in the Find box (as Search criteria) of the document viewer.

What is supposed to match?

Comment: It seems to be an Arabic character. Not sure what this has to do with programming though.

Comment: A poorly formulated question perhaps but looking at Remou's response, I'd considder it programming related and I have learned something new.

Comment: Suggest changing title to "What is" instead of "Who is"

Comment: Changed title as @shufler suggested.

Comment: Honestly, I fail to see the relation to programming. This sounds more like a question that should be on superuser.com.

Comment: This is an option in search engines which support Arabic, so I consider it as programming-related.

Comment: Internationalization is programming-related.

Comment: I don't see how two people voted that this isn't a "real question"!

Comment: @Lieven: The question and answers seem to focus on searching for Arabic characters in IE. How is "searching" programming-related? Wouldn't that make everyone who uses Google a programmer?

Comment: @gnovice: Good one :). Searching in IE explorer isn't offcourse. Searching in and by itself **is** most definitly programming related. I just started reading the Algorithm Design manual and it seems *a lot of* problems are solved by sorting and (yes) searching.

Comment: Closed ? Really ? The **WPF** document viewer has a native search text box, with option "match alef hamza". Developers want to know what it is to explain it to the project supervisor ! It's definitely the good place to ask. Probably a good tag as WPF is just missing.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

> Match alef hamza Specifies whether you
>   want Internet Explorer to match alef
>   characters with hamza or madda when
>   searching for text of Middle Eastern
>   languages.
>
> For example, if you want to find a
>   word that begins with alef and specify
>   match alef hamza, then the word will
>   not be matched if it begins with alef
>   hamza above, alef hamza below, or alef
>   madda. If it is specified, you must
>   enter the correct form of alef for a
>   match.

-- http://www.microsoft.com/middleeast/Arabicdev/IE6/wPapers.aspx

Answer (score 27):

I'm a speaker of Arabic, and Alef Hamza is the character Alef "ا", and Hamza "ء" (or Madda "~") is written with it, like "أ", "إ", or "آ".

So that option means if you want to match Alef only, or Alef with something else.

Example, some search engines consider "è, é, ê or ë" as "e", but others consider them other characters.